# How to inherit from ancestor and not parent in CSS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, plugins, themes

Here is my code:

```
.ancestor { 
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.parent { 
    background-color: #fff;
}

.child {
    /* ??? */
}
```

How can I have `.child` inherit `background-color: #ccc;` **without** changing the class declaration order?

I tried `background-color: inherit;` but all I got is a complete reset (ie no color) of the `background-color` property.

Please also note I can't change neither `.ancestor` nor `.parent`.

Comment: A couple ways to do it, depending on the HTML (which you should add to your question). For example, give the ancestor and child the same class and set the color in that class selector.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could just do this:

```
.ancestor { 
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.parent { 
    background-color: #fff;
}

.child {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

or you could do:

```
.ancestor { 
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.parent { 
    background-color: #fff;
}

.child {
    /* ??? */
}
```

and have

The html div or whatever like this:

```
<div class="ancestor child"></div>
```

Comment: Sure, but the value of `.ancestor` comes from a theme. If the theme changes, it will break the page look and feel.

Comment: OP clearly states "How can I have `.child` **inherit** background-color"

Comment: @Billy yeah sorry fixed it

Comment: I have updated my post for reflecting better my problem.

Answer (score -1):

This would do the trick:

```
.ancestor, .child { 
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.parent { 
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

You can do this,

```
.ancestor { 
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.parent { 
    background-color: #fff;
}

.child {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: The `ancestor` class is defined by a theme. If the theme changes, it will break the page look and feel.

Comment: If you want to format your `child` like your `ancestor` could you not just add the `ancestor` class to your child tags?

Comment: @Dandorid: How do you do that in CSS?

Comment: If you only have a color definition in your `.ancestor` definition you could just write `<htmltag class='child ancestor'>` which would add the color definition of the ancestor to the `<htmltag>`. You leave out the color definition in the child.